# Page is displaying blog archives

Tags: archives

I've been playing around with the jquery plugin Fancybox on this page, but for some reason since making a few changes my page seems to be displaying blog archives rather than the normal content it should be displaying.

I just wondered whether people have had a similar problem? There must be something I've done wrong for this page because all of the other page's content are displaying fine.

This is the code for the portfolio.php page, but it is outputting something completely different.

```
<?php
```

/*
Template Name: Portfolio
*/
?>

```
    <section>
        <?php include("includes/slideshow/slideshow-home.php"); ?>
    </section>
        <header>
            <div id="titleHeader" class="clear">
                <h2 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            </div>
        </header>
        <section>
            <article>
                <div id="mainContent" class="clear">
                    <?php
                    /* Run the loop to output the page.
                     * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
                     * called loop-page.php and that will be used instead.
                     */
                    get_template_part( 'loop', 'page' );
                    ?>
                    <ul id="portfolioContent">
                    <?php
                        $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 10));
                    ?>
                    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
                    <?php
                        $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
                    ?>
                    <li class="portfolioThumb"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="various2"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?></a></li>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
             </article>
         </section>

         <section>
            <aside>
                <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
            </aside>
         </section>

    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Thanks,

Ash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does slideshow-home.php has a loop as well?  You need to ensure that you reset the queries or rewind posts while using multiple Loops `<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>`

[Multiple_Loops](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops)

[Reset Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query)

Comment: slideshow-home.php doesn't have a loop at all. I seem to remember removing a `wp_reset_query` at some point, but it was a while ago and I can't remember - maybe not.

Maybe its something to do with the fancybox jquery I've been editing :S

Comment: try adding it before `$loop = new WP_Query`

Comment: Sorry here's the link to the page:
[http://www.ashleymosuro.com/newsite/porfolio]

Comment: Tried adding that, no luck.

Comment: Hard to know, but I have a feeling that because the post_type is portfolio and the page name is portfolio the function breaks. Did you register portfolio post_types with `'has_archive' => true` ? and maybe this will help as well:
[Custom Post types Archives](http://mark.mcwilliams.me/2010/10/wordpress-3-1-introduces-custom-post-type-archives/)

Comment: I can't imagine its due to the portfolio post type name that its displaying the archive, because it was all working fine before I started changing some things, and i've always had that post-type. I've tried setting has archive to false and now it appears to be displaying a post loop: http://ashleymosuro.com/newsite/portfolio/

Comment: it works fine now? I see the top scroller, the page text and the works gallery

Comment: Ah yes you're right, sorry that was my Firefox's cache playing up probably. Thanks alot Daniel :)

Comment: My pleasure, Ash